# How to Select Distinct Records where a Parameter Value Exists in a column in a different View (Crystal Reports)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a Data Source (SP) that has data in the following format:

```
+----------+-----------+-------+---------+
| Customer | Territory | Date  | Invoice |
+----------+-----------+-------+---------+
| CU1      | A3        | Date1 | I1      |
| CU2      | B2        | Date2 | I2      |
| CU1      | A3        | Date3 | I3      |
+----------+-----------+-------+---------+
```

and so on. There are 8-10 Detail columns in addition to this.

Now, we want to use Crystal Reports with a Parameter for the Territory, which has a hierarchical structure: a Child-Parent Relationship: 
A1 -> A2 -> A3.

What we would like to do is: If A2 is the input parameter, the report should show the data of all customers belonging to A2 or its children i.e. A3 as well.

I have created a View which has this data of the Territories:

```
+-----------+--------+
| Territory | Parent |
+-----------+--------+
| A1        | A1     |
| A2        | A1     |
| A2        | A2     |
| A3        | A1     |
| A3        | A2     |
| A3        | A3     |
+-----------+--------+
```

My way of approaching this is:
If the Input Parameter is one of the PARENTS of the Territory of the Customer, it means the Customer lies in the Selected Territory and hence, select it. Ignore all records who do not have the Parameter as one of the PARENTS.

For this, I created a Left Outer Join between the two Data Sources between the Territories:

```
SP.Territory = View.Territory
```

Then I used the following Record Selection Formula for the Parameter:

```
@TerritoryParam = View.Parent
```

But this is leading to duplicate records. If the number of Child-Parent links are 3 like in A3->A3, A3->A2, A3->A1, all records of the Customer CU1 are being returned 3 times:

```
+----------+-----------+-------+---------+
| Customer | Territory | Date  | Invoice |
+----------+-----------+-------+---------+
| CU1      |    A3     | Date1 | I1      |
| CU1      |    A3     | Date1 | I1      |
| CU1      |    A3     | Date1 | I1      |
| CU1      |    A3     | Date3 | I3      |
| CU1      |    A3     | Date3 | I3      |
| CU1      |    A3     | Date3 | I3      |
+----------+-----------+-------+---------+
```

It has a simple logic behind it but I am not able to get it to work. Can someone please help me out? I would really appreciate it.

Edit: if Multiple Values are selected in CR i.e. Suppose the user selects both A1 and A2, only one record should be displayed, not two. I understand my formula above will fail to do that.

If you instead have a way I can modify the SP in MS-SQL instead for achieving the goal, I would appreciate it. The only condition is that I cannot include the @TerritoryParam parameter in the SP as that makes it mandatory in the Crystal Report and we need to keep it optional.

Comment: Have you looked into using Sub Reports that are linked back to the main report using the the fields that define the child parent relationship?

Comment: Hello, I thought of that. For every record, I get the Sub-Report correctly. Customer A of Territory A3. Sub-Report has 2 columns: Child: A3, A3, A3. Parent: A1, A2, A3. But now, how do I select the record based on the Sub-Report: If @Parameter exists in the Parent Column of the Sub-Report of the Record, Select Record.

Comment: I think you might be able to make that work with some Group Levels on A1 > A2 > A3.  Use a sub report in the A1 group section for the first relationship, then another sub report in each of the A2 and A3 group sections.  Avoid using the Details section as this is where you will end up with duplicate records.  I feel like I'm still missing something though, so I made this a comment instead of an answer.  If it provides some progress I can flesh it out into an answer that where we can continue working through it.

Comment: Hello, we don't require separate groups for A1, A2, A3. In fact, these are completely dynamic. I'll try to explain using a real-life example. USA (country) is A1. New York (state) is A2, which belongs to A1. Queens (Area) is A3, which belongs to A2. These are my territories. I have a customer in Queens (A3). In my Crystal Report, I have to select a parameter for Territory. If I select Queens, all records of the customer should be seen. If I select NY, all records of all customers who are in or belong to NY should be seen. Also, if I select both NY and Queens, only one should be seen.

Comment: By dynamic, I mean, we can keep on increasing the levels: A4, A5, etc. Our selection check has to be on: If the Inpur Parameter is one of the Parents, select it. Meaning: A3 has parents: A3, A2, A1. If my input is A2, CR should see A2 is one of the parents of A3, so select the record of A3. If my input is A1, CR sees A1 is one of the parents of A3, so select the record of A3. If my input is A4, CR sees A4 is not one of the parents of A3, don't select it.